# Sort listview by date Android

Tags: android, listview, sorting

I got a custom listview which contains info about tv shows, ie. show title, last episode, last episode date, next episode, next episode date an so on.

Now I want to sort the listview ie. by last episode date. The shows are stored in an Arraylist, and the date is stored as a string in the format MMM/dd/yyyy.

```
Sort by title works with follow code:

    public void sortByTitle() {
        Comparator<Show> comperator = new Comparator<Show>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Show object1, Show object2) {
                return object1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(
                        object2.getTitle());
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(dataFromDB, comperator);
        lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(this, dataFromDB));
    }
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: are you getting data from db ? What is dataFromDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as you are sorting on the basis of title,can be done with dates also.
Example:

```
 // sort by date
    public int compareTo(NewsDetails another) 
    {
        if (another == null) return 1;
        // sort descending, most recent first
        return another.date.compareTo(date);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, how? Because then I let it sort on date it only sort by MMM alphabeatical.

Comment: In Show class, do you have DateTime variable? If so then compare dates. If you have date in string format then convert them into Date and then compare

Comment: @Sandy In compatreTo(date) code ,which date should pass..?

Comment: @Pranav: You are comparing 2 dates, date1.comapretTo(date2).

Answer (score 4):

Store your dates as strings in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. Comparing two date strings in this format will always guarantee getting an ascending/descending sort order.

Comment: This is called ISO format. It's also used for storing dates in SQLite, which are treated as strings. You can also add time information: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @Klaus66 : **"This is called ISO format"** Not technically true. It is called big-endian date format although if you're alluding to ISO8601 then you are correct that big-endian format is used by default. Also SQLite has two other ways to treat date/time fields - REAL (the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C) and INTEGER (the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC as per Unix Time). The SQLite date/time functions do work with (and return) ISO8601 formats but can handle conversions between the other data types.

Comment: Every day I learn something I didn't know before - thank you for your clarifications!

Comment: Actually i used dd-mm-yyy format but its sorted in wrong way, after saw your comment i changed into dd-MM-yyyy (MM in Capital Letter) then its worked fine. Thank You!

Comment: @KarthickPandiyan : Yes - mm (lower case) is for minutes. You need to use MM (upper case) for month as you have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have all the data in ArrayList and in you have two ArrayLists, one contains the date and its corresponding indexes in another ArrayList have other details about the TV Shows, you're supposed to be sorting both the ArrayLists on the basis of Dates stored in the ArrayList that holds date, and then provide the ListView adapter with it.

You can construct a Date object with the date time and then sort them.

Was this helpful?