# how can i put data in list view month wise in android?

Tags: android-listview, android-sqlite

I want to show data in database as month wise. Means the number of activities done by user for particular months display in particular month. 
Like,

1  April 2013

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

---

2  May 2013

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

the data are coming in list-view from database. How can i do this, If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: Have you get answer for this question? @Raj

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the date first using `Comparator` and `Collections.sort` and then populate the listview as per each month. You can also check number of months have data and populate only those listviews. But Best way to solve this problem is by using expandable Listview. Check this link

[Expandable Listview](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-game-programming/simple-expandable-list-example/)

[For Sorting by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323063/sort-listview-by-date-android)

I hope it will atleast give you idea to start work on.